# TextBox mysteriously losing focus

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So I have got this UpdatePanel in which there is this TextBox. Whenever I click in it, it focuses and then loses the focus in less than a second. Therefore one seem unable to write anything inside the TextBox. How do I solve this issue?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="updateTimer" Interval="1000" OnTick="updateTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        <div>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="4" ScrollBars="Vertical">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="chatLabel"></asp:Literal>
            </asp:Panel>           
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="chatTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4" AutoPostBack="true" OnKeyPress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="chatSubmit" OnClick="chatSubmit_Click" Text="Send"/>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<script>
    function EnterEvent(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            __doPostBack('<%= chatSubmit.UniqueID %>', "");
        }
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to do that.  On key press, you trigger an async postback, and that is what is causing you to lose the focus.  you would have to use javascript, and use

```
Sys.Application.add_endRequest(function(sender, e) { })
```

To listen for the end of the request and put the focus back.

I see what you are trying to do, and I would highly recommend using a web service, or Signalr, to do what you want to do.  You are not going to get the ability or performance you are looking for.  An update panel takes focus away as it posts back, and so the user can't just keep typing.  The update panel is somewhat restrictive that way.