# textBox Lose focus on nested Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two nested `Gridviews`, the parent is for Posts and child is for Comments. I want to update Post and Comments with a Time Interval so Im using an asp.net Timer. My problem is that a `TextBox` that is in the first `Gridview` loses focus when timer Ticks. I searched the web a lot, one possible solution was to take the textbox out of the `UpdatePanel` but in this situation I can't take out the `textBox`. Please help me, here is my code.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <%--post GridView--%>
        <asp:GridView ID="posts" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%--Comments Gridview--%>
                        <asp:GridView ID="comments" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                        <%--a Textbox and bUtton For sending new Comment--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    posts.DataSource = GetData();
    posts.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to type a similar answer to this, but it appears it has already been explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22014420/2248290

The key point being: "An update panel takes focus away as it posts back"